# merge two images into one image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to merge two images into one image, here is my code:

```
-(UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)mask overImage:(UIImage*)source inSize:(CGSize)size
{
    //Capture image context ref

    UIImageView *totalimage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

    UIImageView *firstImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:mask];
    UIImageView *secondImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:source];

    [totalimage addSubview:firstImage];
    [totalimage addSubview:secondImage];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(totalimage.bounds.size);
    [totalimage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Draw images onto the context
    [source drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, source.size.width, source.size.height)]; 
    [mask drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, mask.size.width, mask.size.height)]; 

    return viewImage;

}
```

I call this method as follows:

```
UIImage *totalImage = [self mergeImage:self.Apicimage overImage:questionImage inSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
```

but on execution I get this output:

```
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
Jun 15 16:11:06 iPad-2 VueGuides[9195] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

can anyone guide me please. How can I merge two images?

Comment: in addition to ArunGJ's answer, which is correct, you're not actually using your `CGSize` parameter you pass in.

Answer (score 3):

your code

```
[source drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, source.size.width, source.size.height)]; 
    [mask drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, mask.size.width, mask.size.height)];
```

should be written before

```
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```